# Laravel 7.2.2: AuthenticationException with AuthenticateSession middleware when using auth()->login() and redirect() and route('login')

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a Laravel application from start with user login/registration function.
Below is some code of it:

```
// web.php
Route::middleware(['guest'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/register', 'UserController@register');
    Route::post('/register', 'UserController@doRegister')->middleware('throttle:10,1');

    Route::get('/login', 'UserController@login')->name('login');
    Route::post('/login', 'UserController@doLogin')->middleware('throttle:15,1');
});
Route::get('/logout', 'UserController@logout');

// UserController.php
class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function register()
    {
        return view('user.register');
    }

    public function doRegister(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:App\User',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed'
        ]);
        
        $userData = $request->only(['name', 'email']);
        $userData['password'] = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
        $user = User::create($userData);
        
        auth()->login($user);
        return redirect("/");
    }

    use ThrottlesLogins;
    protected $maxAttempts=5;
    protected $decayMinutes=1;

    public function login()
    {
        return view('user.login');
    }

    public function doLogin(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
        if (auth()->attempt($request->only(['email', 'password']), $request->boolean('remember_password')) == false) {
            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
            return back()->withErrors([
                'message' => __('auth.failed')
            ])->with('email', $request->input('email'));
        }
        
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }

    protected function username()
    {
        return 'email';
    }
    
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }
}
```

The web page seem working.
When I enable middleware `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class`in Kernel.php (for trial function "Invalidating Sessions On Other Devices" later), following error happen:

After creating new user success and redirect to home page with `redirect("/")`, `Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException: Unauthenticated` will happen and redirect again to login page (expected must go to home page with logged user).

Stacktrace:

```
E:\Web\movie-resumer\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession.php:94
Stack trace:
#0 E:\Web\movie-resumer\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession.php(55): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession->logout(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
```

This trace refer to following code in AuthenticateSession.php:

```
class AuthenticateSession
{
    
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        ...

        if ($request->session()->get('password_hash') !== $request->user()->getAuthPassword()) {
            $this->logout($request);
        }

       ...
    }
}
```

I just try with other replacement as below in `UserController@doRegister` method:

- Change `auth()->login($user);` to use `auth()->attempt($request->only(['email', 'password']));` then Exception will not occur
- Or: change `return redirect("/");` to use `return view('home');` then Exception will not occur (the URL `http://localhost/register` will show the home page with logged user)
- Or: change/remove the route name 'login' (`Route::get('/login', 'UserController@login')->name('login123');`) then Exception will not occur.

Do my first implement has any mistake, so that it cannot working with AuthenticateSession middleware?

Comment: You should redirect to / only when attempt returns a success, not the other way around, redirecting back if attempt failed

Comment: This is what I did in my code, after `auth()->login($user);` success, then it call `return redirect("/");`

Comment: You are getting autologged out: `        if ($request->session()->get('password_hash') !== $request->user()->getAuthPassword()) {
            $this->logout($request);
        }
` I think auth()->login() is good for stateless requests only... Use official way to auth user.